# How to join two matrices and then find rate in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have two matrices with the same labels.

How to join them and find a rate for the last 5 min.

```
(custom_rules_actions_time_sum + custom_rules_variables_time_sum)[5m]
```

It throws an error: `Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': 1:69: parse error: unexpected "]" in subquery selector, expected ":"`

Comment: Try out `custom_rules_actions_time_sum[5m] + custom_rules_variables_time_sum[5m]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the rate first:

```
  rate(custom_rules_actions_time_sum[5m]) 
+ 
  rate(custom_rules_variables_time_sum[5m]
```

It's possible that actions and variables should be exposed as label values rather than as part of metric names.